# Blazor: Drag & Drop list elements

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, blazor

I would like to know how to bind Drag & Drop events to rearrange items in a list.

This is the code I have:

```
<PageTitle>Drag & Drop</PageTitle>

<ul style="border:1px solid black">
    @foreach (var item in Items)
    {
        <li draggable="true" @* draggable *@
            @key=@item.Id
            id="@item.Id"              
            @* how to bind drag events? *@
        >@item.Label</li>
    }
</ul>

@code {
    public class Item
    {
        public int Id {get; set;}
        public string Label {get; set; } = default!;
    }
    public List<Item> Items = new() {
        new Item(){Id= 1, Label = "hi 1"},
        new Item(){Id= 2, Label = "hi 2"},
        new Item(){Id= 3, Label = "hi 3"},
        new Item(){Id= 4, Label = "Move me!"},
    };

}
```

Comment: You can use Mudblazor Drop Zone : https://mudblazor.com/components/dropzone#basic-usage

Comment: @LYass, good point! I will dig into Mudblazor source code. I guess Mudblazor is no design agnostic, is based on Material.

Comment: @LYass, after digging into Mudblazor source code, I saw that MudBlazor basics does the same as the answer below. Obviously, MudBlazor is more completed and tested that answer below, reading code I can appreciate a very good work and  Blazoristic compliant (c# good code and almost no JS). Also, I didn't found in Mudblazor options to set "move" on `event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed`. I guess all us with the same Blazor limitations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here I illustrate some basic Drag & Drop html5 event handling operations just with Blazor:

[image]

Here is the code, self explanatory.

```
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Drag & Drop Sample</PageTitle>

<ul style="border:1px solid black">
    @foreach (var item in Items)
    {
        <li draggable="true"
            class="@(DragEnter==item?"inserting":"")"
            @key=@item.Id
            id="@item.Id"              
            ondragover="event.preventDefault();"
            @ondragstart="@( (e) => hondragstart(e, item))"
            @ondrop="@( () => hondropOverAFriend(item))"
            @ondragenter="@( ()=> hondragenter(item) )"
            @ondragend="@( ()=> hondragend() )"
        >@item.Label</li>
    }
    <div style="height: 1.5em;" 
        ondragover="event.preventDefault();"
        @ondrop="hondropBotton"
        @ondragenter="hondragenterBotton"
    />
</ul>

<style>
    .inserting
    {
        border-top: 1px solid black;
        margin-top: 5px;
    }
</style>

@code {
    public class Item
    {
        public int Id {get; set;}
        public string Label {get; set; } = default!;
    }
    public List<Item> Items = new() {
        new Item(){Id= 1, Label = "hi 1"},
        new Item(){Id= 2, Label = "hi 2"},
        new Item(){Id= 3, Label = "hi 3"},
        new Item(){Id= 4, Label = "Move me!"},
    };
    public void  hondropOverAFriend(Item friend)
    {
        DragEnter=null;
        if (DraggedItem == null) return;
        if (DraggedItem == friend) return;
        var friendposition = Items.IndexOf(friend);
        Items.Insert(friendposition, DraggedItem!);
        DraggedItem=null;
    }
    public void  hondropBotton()
    {
        DragEnter=null;
        if (DraggedItem == null) return;
        Items.Add(DraggedItem!);
        DraggedItem=null;
    }
    public void  hondragstart(DragEventArgs e, Item item)
    {
        e.DataTransfer.EffectAllowed = "move"; //does't run
        DraggedItem = item;
        DraggedItemPosition = Items.IndexOf(item);
        Items.Remove(DraggedItem!);
    }    
    public void  hondragenter(Item item)
        =>
        DragEnter = item;    
    public void  hondragenterBotton()
        =>
        DragEnter = null;
    public void  hondragend()
    {
        // never fired IDK why
        if (DraggedItem == null) return;        
        DragEnter = null;
        Items.Insert(DraggedItemPosition, DraggedItem!);        
    }
    private Item? DraggedItem;
    private int DraggedItemPosition;
    private Item? DragEnter;
}
```

**Disclaimer**

They are some things that I don't know how to do without JSInterop, for example, I was unable to change `EffectAllowed` or to set data on `DataTransfer`. People, be free to improve code!

Comment: Thank you for this answer. If only all answers were this clear and good

Comment: why the "h" prefix here as a naming convention for all the events?  e.g. hondragend vs ondragend?

Comment: @frigon lol, no, no conventions. i don't remember why. Be free to fix it.

Comment: One comment here - I think this may only work for Blazor Server. With Blazor WASM, when you call items.Remove at the start of the drag, it results in the item being dragged being removed from the DOM. Could probably get around by copying it to create the drag handle....

Answer (score 0):

If you change `@ondragend="@(()=> hondragend())"` to `@ondragend="hondragend"`
It will fire the event on your code